# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named sklearn

Tags: scikit-learn, anaconda3

When I run:

```
from sklearn import datasets
```

I get the error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn'
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you basically not installed sklearn library.. so first install sklearn with below command.

`pip install sklearn`

and then run the code it will resolve your issue.

Comment: From `poetry add sklearn` `poetry show`: `sklearn 0.0.post1   deprecated sklearn package, use scikit-learn instead`. Installing `scikit-learn` resolves the `sklearn` dependency.

Answer (score 32):

You may also try to install: scikit-learn

```
pip install scikit-learn
```

or via Conda:

```
conda install scikit-learn
```

Comment: This is the only correct answer going forward, as the pypi `sklearn` package is being deprecated, and will error on install in every instance at the end of 2023.

Comment: @LiHRaM Is it being deprecated or is it deprecated?

Comment: @MehdiCharife My bad. It _is_ deprecated according to the `sklearn` package on pypi: https://pypi.org/project/sklearn/.

My wording was due to the brownout schedule, where trying to install `sklearn` fails more and more often until it always errors at end of 2023, but it is already deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

This confused me after reading several posts about this.

To make sure I was installing to the right Python, I did this:

```
python -m pip install sklearn
```

It said

```
Requirement already satisfied: sklearn in /home/.../lib/python3.10/site-packages (0.0.post5)
```

Then I typed `python` to get the prompt and then `import sklearn`. It said `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn'`. But I just installed it, right? Wrong!

I ran `python -m pip show sklearn` and it said

```
Name: sklearn
Version: 0.0.post5
Summary: deprecated sklearn package, use scikit-learn instead
```

This is saying `sklearn` isn't the package to install to get the module `sklearn`. Instead I should install `scikit-learn` to get the module `sklearn`.

So I ran `python -m pip uninstall sklearn` and then `python -m pip install scikit-learn`. Now when I open `python` and type `import sklearn` it imports scikit-learn.

I feel this is unnecessarily confusing (that sklearn isn't installed as sklearn) so I'm posting here in hopes that it helps someone else.

Answer (score -1):

If PIP is already installed on you PC, its just a matter of running a single command `pip install sklearn` and it will install the sklearn module easily. You can refer to `https://scikit-learn.org/stable/install.html`.

else you will need to install pip. Refer `https://phoenixnap.com/kb/install-pip-windows` for PIP installation.